# How to selectively style certain li and ul elements?

Tags: css

I have designed a navigation bar for my website using the following CSS:

```
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size:90%;
}

li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #e67300;
}
</style>
```

This is a version of the horizontal navigation bar example documented at w3schools.com: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black

My problem is that it affects other `<li>` and `<ul>` elements used in my website as well, not just the navbar. How do I ensure the navbar ones stay separate from other `<li>` and `<ul>` elements, using solely CSS? I've started learning CSS quite recently, so I'm certain I'm missing something pretty fundamental here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use may want to use `css classes`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

```
ul.mylist {
    .....
}

ul.mylist li {
    .....
}

ul.mylist li a {
    .....
}

ul.mylist li a:hover {
    .....
}
```

Also make sure to add the class to the html

```
<ul class='mylist'>
    <li>......
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to man's answer, enclose the `ul` elements in a `div` and set the class of the `div` to `navbar`, for example. Then change your CSS code to this:

```
ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size:90%;
}

ul.navbar li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

ul.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #e67300;
}
```

Comment: But then how do I call this CSS in the html?

Comment: @HassanBaig Use `<ul class="navbar">`

Comment: Makes sense. So I just call it with `ul`, e.g. `<ul class="navbar">`, and don't have to worry about enclosed `<li>` elements.

Comment: @HassanBaig Click the check icon underneath the down arrow underneath the '3' if this answer helped you.

Comment: Bennet, I've marked man's answer as the best one. Yours was good (I upvoted it), yet his was more complete given it contained the HTML part in the main answer body.

Comment: @HassanBaig Okay. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I'll modify your code to demonstrate how you can use **classes** to specify which `ul` tag you wish to style

```
<style>
    ul.myNav { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        background-color: #ff9933; 
        font-size:90%; 
    } 

    ul.myNav > li { 
        float: left; 
        border-right: 1px solid #ffb366; 
    } 

    ul.myNav > li a { 
        display: block; 
        color: white; 
        text-align: center; 
        padding-left: 10px; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        padding-top: 3px; 
        padding-bottom: 3px; 
        text-decoration: none; 
    } 

    ul.myNav > li a:hover { 
        background-color: #e67300; 
    } 
</style>
```

And all you have to do is add the class to your preferred `ul` element in your html.

```
<ul class="myNav"> .... </ul>
```

Comment: What's the `>` operator?

Comment: `x > y` means : `y` that is a direct child of `x`, not grandchild or more. Not so necessary in this context anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
li:not(:first-child){
 code...
}
li:not(:last-child){
  code...
```